# Extract a non ZIP file to files on disk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, vscode-extensions, dynamics-business-central

I got a App File which is structured like a zip file.
Now I would like to extract all of the files in the app file.

I tried to convert the app to a zip file in the code (just copy and paste as zip file), but then it's a "SFX ZIP Archive", which most of the unzipper in node.js can't read.

For example AdmZip (error message):

> rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: Invalid CEN
> header (bad signature)

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
var admZip2 = new AdmZip("C:\\temp\\Test\\Microsoft_System.zip");
admZip2.extractAllTo("C:\\temp\\Test\\System", true)
```

So now i don't know how to deal with it, because I need to extract the files with all subfolder/subfiles to a specific folder on the computer.

How would you do this?

You can download the .app file here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i7v_SsRwJdykhxu_rJzRCAOmam5dAt-9/view?usp=sharing

If you open it, you should see something like this:

[image: App file in WinRar]

Thanks for your help :)

**EDIT:**

I'm already using JSZip for resaving the zip file as a normal ZIP Archive. But this is a extra step which costs some time.

Maybe someone knows how to extract files to a path with JSZip :)

**EDIT 2:**

Just for you information: It's a VS Code Extension Project

**EDIT 3:**
I got something which worked for me.
For my solution I did it with Workers (Because parallel)

```
var zip = new JSZip();
zip.loadAsync(data).then(async function (contents) {
zip.remove('SymbolReference.json');
zip.remove('[Content_Types].xml');
zip.remove('MediaIdListing.xml');
zip.remove('navigation.xml');
zip.remove('NavxManifest.xml');
zip.remove('Translations');
zip.remove('layout');
zip.remove('ProfileSymbolReferences');
zip.remove('addin');
zip.remove('logo');

//workerdata.files = Object.keys(contents.files)
//so you loop through contents.files and foreach file you get the dirname
//then check if the dir exists (create if not)
//after this you create the file with its content
//you have to rewrite some code to fit your code, because this whole code are
//from 2 files, hope it helps someone :)

Object.keys(workerData.files.slice(workerData.startIndex, workerData.endIndex)).forEach(function (filename, index) {
  workerData.zip.file(filename).async('nodebuffer').then(async function (content) {
    var destPath = path.join(workerData.baseAppFolderApp, filename);
    var dirname = path.dirname(destPath);

    // Create Directory if is doesn't exists
    await createOnNotExist(dirname);

    files[index] = false;
    fs.writeFile(destPath, content, async function (err) {
        // This is code for my logic
        files[index] = true;
        if (!files.includes(false)) {
            parentPort.postMessage(workerData);
        };
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

I'm currently in the process of having to extract .app files but I'm not finding anything to solve this on the interwebs. With the screenshot it looks like you are extracting app files too?

Comment: @Holm76 I added my solution code.
Maybe it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not able to make it work with your code but it did indeed help my to find a solution that worked for me with minor changes. Now I just need to figure out a way to make the extract code run in a synced maner some how instead of using callbacks. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsZip is A library for creating, reading and editing .zip files with JavaScript, with a lovely and simple API.

link (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip)

example (extraction)

```
var JSZip = require('JSZip');

fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        var zip = new JSZip();
        zip.loadAsync(data).then(function(contents) {
            Object.keys(contents.files).forEach(function(filename) {
                zip.file(filename).async('nodebuffer').then(function(content) {
                    var dest = path + filename;
                    fs.writeFileSync(dest, content);
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is a valid zip file appended to some sort of executable.
The easiest way is to extract it calling an unzipper such as unzipada.exe - free, open-source software available [here](https://unzip-ada.sourceforge.io/). Pre-built Windows executables available in the Files section.

Comment: well, this is not javascript or node.js.
I need some sort of javascript/node.js package for this.

Comment: Google for "spawn javascript". I've found this: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: But the problem is, it's a vscode extension. So it's not a very good idea to work with executable child process`s